# In "Lesson one", should I use одӣн, одна or одно?

Tags: разница

I want to write "Lesson 1" in Russian.
Is the sentence "Урок одӣн" correct? Or should I write "одно" or "одна"?

What way is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

- Урок номер один (not одӣн!)

That means literally "Lesson number one"

Or you could say

- Первый урок/ Урок первый

That means literally "First lesson".

A couple of other points:

- одӣн seems like a misspelling of один. Russian doesn't have the letter *ӣ* (but does have *й*)
- одно is neuter and одна is feminine. In the example above, номер is masculine and so is один, and they have to match in gender

Comment: Thank you! 
I'm french and in french "lesson" is feminine. That's why I thought I could use одна. Now I know it's masculine in russian.
I have a russian keyboard with the letter ӣ when I press the и key for a long time. I don't know why then. But you're right it should be й

Comment: You could always just write "Урок 1".

Comment: @DanM. I'm pretty sure that would just be read as "урок первый".

Comment: @OmarL depends on the context. If it's a homework assignment, "Урок 1, задание 2" can be read as just "урок один, задание два" (with implicit "номер").